# ShowGridLines merges columns while exporting Crystal Report to

Tags: c#, .net, excel, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I am trying to Export Crystal report 2013 to excel . The issue arises when I set 'XLSFormatOptions.ShowGridLines'  to 'true'. The column cells merge themselves. However, they do not merge if 'XLSFormatOptions.ShowGridLines'  is not set to "true"  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcRFV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLWxy.png)

Comment: Please show us a small example.

Comment: Please find the image attached